# Text input with wacom drawing tablet

Tags: 13.04, windows-7, wacom, graphics-tablet

On Windows 7 when tapping a text entry field with the tablet pen an on screen keyboard or handwritten-text tool would pop up allowing me to write out text and hit the insert button.

Is there anything similar to this on Ubuntu? (13.04)

This is what I'm talking about if you're unfamiliar:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Installing Cellwriter

Cellwriter regonizes handwriting and transforms it into text.

[Cellwriter on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbjaGjlwOA4)

You need to activate the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Then you can install cellwriter with

```
sudo apt-get install cellwriter
```

There is some more good info to lift from this archived [post](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/CellWriter/) written in german. You can ask google to translate it for you [here](https://wiki-ubuntuusers-de.translate.goog/Archiv/CellWriter/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=de&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp).

Comment: Something is wrong with that program. During the training where you teach it to recognize your handwriting by tracing over letters you cannot lift the pen for characters that require it. For example when teaching it a lowercase t it treats the vertical stroke and horizontal stroke as separate attempts at a "t". This creates a problem where any vertical stroke or horizontal stroke will be recognized as a "t". Seems broken. Thanks though.

Comment: Don't need to draw characters exactly how they look in training mode, you can "invent" a streak for every one. This message was written with Cellwriter and a Wacom tablet by the way.